# Flink Streaming RichSource early stops

Tags: flink-streaming

It runs with processing time and using a broadcast state.

```
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);


    BroadcastStream<List<TableOperations>> broadcastOperationsState = env
                .addSource(new LoadCassandraOperations(10000L, cassandraHost, cassandraPort)).broadcast(descriptor);

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<InternalVariableValue> stream = 
                env.addSource(new SourceMillisInternalVariableValue(5000L));

        
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<InternalVariableOperation> streamProcessed = 
                stream
                .keyBy(InternalVariableValue::getUuid)
                .connect(broadcastOperationsState)
                .process(new AddOperationInfo())
                ;

        

streamProcessed.print();
```

SourceMillisIntervalVariableValues create a event every 5s . The events are stored in a static collection. The run method looks like :

```
    public class SourceMillisInternalVariableValue extends RichSourceFunction<InternalVariableValue>{
    
    private boolean running;
    
    long millis;

    public SourceMillisInternalVariableValue(long millis) {
        super();
        this.millis = millis;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<InternalVariableValue> ctx) throws Exception {        
        //Espera inicial
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        PojoVariableValues[] pojoData =
                 new PojoVariableValues[]{
                  new PojoVariableValues("id1", "1"),
                  new PojoVariableValues("id2", "2"),
                 ....
                 ....
                  new PojoVariableValues("id21", "21")
                         };
        
         int cont = 0;
         while (cont<pojoData.length) {
            System.out.println("Iteration "+cont+" "+pojoData.length);
            ctx.collect(generateVar(pojoData[0+cont].getUUID(), pojoData[0+cont].getValue()));      
            ctx.collect(generateVar(pojoData[1+cont].getUUID(), pojoData[1+cont].getValue()));      
            ctx.collect(generateVar(pojoData[2+cont].getUUID(), pojoData[2+cont].getValue()));      
            cont = cont +3;
            Thread.sleep(millis);       
        }
        
    }
    
    private InternalVariableValue generateVar(String uuid, String value)
    {
        return InternalVariableValueMessage.InternalVariableValue.newBuilder()
                .setUuid(uuid)
                .setTimestamp(new Date().getTime()).setValue(value).setKeyspace("nest").build();
    }
    
    class PojoVariableValues {
        private String UUID;
        private String Value;
        
        public PojoVariableValues(String uUID, String value) {
            super();
            UUID = uUID;
            Value = value;
        }
        
        public String getUUID() {
            return UUID;
        }
        public void setUUID(String uUID) {
            UUID = uUID;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return Value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            Value = value;
        }
        
       }
}
```

LoadCassandraOperations emits events every 10 seconds. It works fine.

When I run this code, SourceMillisIntervalVariableValues stops in the first iteration, emiting only three events. If I comment the **process** function, both sources works properly, but if I run the **process** , the source is cancel...

I spect than the source emits all events ( 21 exactly ) , and all of them are processing in the aggregate function. If I run this code, the while loop in the sources only complete one iteration.

Any idea ?

Thank youuu . cheers

EDIT:

Important. This code is for explore the processint time and broadcast feature. I know  that I'm not using the best practices in the sources. Thanks

EDIT 2:
The problem starts when I try to run the process function.

Comment: The first problem I see is that at some point the source is going to run off the end of the `pojoData` and throw an exception. Also, `SourceFunction.SourceContext#collect` only takes one argument, so it's not clear what's going on there. Without seeing the whole pipeline, it's hard to guess what's happening. Do you have a sink? And what do you mean by "the source is cancelled"?

Comment: Thank you for your time !. All right.

- You are right with the exception , I don't understand why the program is NOT throwing the exception ... but okey, I can change the while condition.



- I add to the question all ( mostly ) source code, the only argument is the time that the while loop must wait between iterations.

- Yes, I have a sink, but its not important now ( I guess  :))

- " the source is cancelled " means that the cancel() method in the source is executed before run method has finished

Thank you for yor time and sorry for my english

Comment: More info: If I change streamProcessed.print() to stream.print() , the source function works properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!

The problem was that I try to run it using a TestContainer and I can't watch any logs.

I ran it with a simple main method and I can see some code errors ( like the commented in the comments. Tnks !!! ).